# From where PrincipalContext gets the connected server name?

Tags: c#, active-directory, windows-authentication, iis-8

I have a web application with windows authentication. When I debug the line

```
var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "abc");
```

where "abc" is domain name.

I can see the connected server as domain controller name. I would like to know from where it is getting the DC name.

Actually, the issue is, even though a particular DC is demoted and new DC is added, our application always pointing to the same demoted DC and throws error when we try to get groups of the user using the below lines.

```
var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, "username");
var groups = user.GetGroups();
```

> [ActiveDirectoryServerDownException: The server is not operational.
>
> Name: "DomainController.Domain.com"
>
> ]
>
> System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.PropertyManager.GetPropertyValue(DirectoryContext
>   context, DirectoryEntry directoryEntry, String propertyName) +510
>
> System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryEntryManager.ExpandWellKnownDN(WellKnownDN
>   dn) +239
>
> System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DomainController.get_Domain()
>   +71
>
> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.GetGroupsMemberOf(Principal
>   p) +839
>
> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.GetGroups() +32

Do I need to clear IIS cache or some other cache? I have restarted the IIS too.

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the `DC` name programmatically **if your server belongs to domain controller**.

```
    using (var context = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        server = context.ConnectedServer; 
        //Output : dc.example.com
        var formatted = server.Split('.').Select(s => String.Format("DC={0}", s));
        joined = String.Join(",", formatted); 
        // Output DC=dc,DC=example,DC=com
    }
```

**If the server isn't a part of the domain controller**. You can retrieve it by using credentials like this;

```
        System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext domainContext = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, "domainName", "domainUser", "Password");
        var domain = ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetDomain(domainContext);
        var controller = domain.FindDomainController();
```

Comment: Thank you Rainman. But the issue is, this application was working early and this is happened during a maintenance period of DCs. Just curious to know where the DCs names are saved and from where it is getting that. I can add the new DC name. But, in future, if they change this, then again I need to change the configuration.

Comment: Thank you for the code. I would like to know, the line server = context.ConnectedServer; from where it is getting the DCs name.

Comment: I couldn't understand what exactly are you asking ? DC is itself of connectedserver. DC=dc,DC=example,DC=com

Comment: Please check the line from my question "Actually, the issue is, even though a particular DC is demoted and new DC is added, our application always pointing to the same demoted DC and throws error when we try to get groups of the user using the below lines." So, the line context.ConnectedServer provides only old demoted DC and not the added new DC. So, I would like to know where the DC names are saved and form where it is giving me the old DC name. What should I need to do to get the new DC name. Thank you for your time..

Comment: I couldn't figure out. You are trying to retrieve DC name using the code I provided above and still getting old DC Name. Is it true ? Actually, it is impossible. I think; you should check Active directory server. Because the DC Names are not stored anywhere except AD, you retrieve from AD directly.

Comment: It's locator service, that queries your dns server, which returns the closest available domain controller. When locator gets one, it pings it (sort of) to check that the server is available. Then it cashes the domain controller. So you need to clear cache by restarting dc locator service or provide dc to principal context (recommended)